# Best resource for memory footprint analysis for winforms app . 

Tags: c#, memory

So we have a winforms app that in the task manager should anywhere from 250 - 450 MB of memory.  We are trying to figure out the best place to focus on to reduce memory footprint.

what is the best place to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest profiling so you can understand what is using the memory. CLR Profiler and ANTS Profiler are two profilers you may want to check out.

Answer (score 0):

[Yourkit](http://yourkit.com/) is better than the other suggested profilers.